# Angular Identifier 'playerType' is not defined. '' does not contain such a member

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on an ionic app, where I am fetching value using `*ngFor="let playerValue of players"`, in HTML file

But I am getting error on using property of playerValue like  playerPhoto or playerType  in html while    interpolation `{{playerValue.playerPhoto}}` or `playerValue.playerType` 
eg : -

```
<img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}></button>
```

or

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="playerValue.playerType">
```

error message is -:

> [Angular] Identifier 'playerType' is not defined. '' does
>   not contain such a member

or

> [Angular] Identifier 'playerPhoto' is not defined. '' does
>   not contain such a member

html where I am getting the error

```html
<ion-content no-padding>
  <div class="create-team-section">
    <ion-list class="team-create-list">
      <div [ngSwitch]="playerType" *ngFor="let playerValue of players |
          search : terms| sort: {property: column, order: order}; let i = index">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="playerValue.playerType" ngSelected="selected">
          <ion-item [class.active]="playerValue.isSelected? 'active' : null">
            <ion-grid no-padding>
              <!-- <a (click)="playerInfo()"><img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}></a> -->
              <ion-row align-items-center [class.shake]="shake==playerValue.playerUid ? 'shake' : null">
                <ion-col col-3>
                  <!-- <div class="create-team-imge" >
                      <img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}>
                    </div> -->
                  <div class="create-team-imge">
                    <ion-avatar item-star no-line>
                      <button (click)="playerinfo(i)"><img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}></button>
                    </ion-avatar>
                    <ion-badge>
                      <ion-icon name="information"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-badge>
                  </div>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-md-9 col-9 (click)="setClickedRow(i)">
                  <ion-row align-items-center>
                    <ion-col col-md-8 col-7>

                      <p>{{playerValue.playerName}}</p>
                      <p>Selected By {{playerValue.selectedBy}}</p>
                      <p class="country" >{{playerValue.teamName}}</p>
                      <p class="points"> Points:
                        <span>{{playerValue.totalPoint}}</span>
                      </p>
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col col-md-4 col-5 class="cradit">
                      <p>
                        <span>{{playerValue.playerCreditPoint}}</span>
                      </p>
                      <button ion-button icon-only>
                        <ion-icon [name]="playerValue.isSelected? 'close' : 'ios-checkmark'"></ion-icon>
                      </button>
                    </ion-col>
                  </ion-row>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
          </ion-item>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

ts file

```ts
export class CreateteamPage {

  players: any = [];
```

Comment: Maybe try removing '[ngSwitch]="playerType" on your *ngFor first as it seems to be using one of your player properties.

Comment: What does it show when you put `{{playerValue | json}}` ?

Comment: How is playerValue defined ?

Comment: @selemmn it is coming correctly in { "key" : "value" , "key" : "value"   } format

Comment: @DelwynPinto It is defined in json

Comment: @AnuragRanjan could you share the object ? Also, can you confirm that the object is being defined before the HTML gets rendered ?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an interface like this

```
export interface Players {
 playerType: string;
 playerPhoto: string;
}
```

And in your ts file:

```
import { Players } from './models/players' // path to the interface

export class CreateteamPage {

 players: Players[];

 // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: error is fixed but , because of creating interface I am getting another error 



[ts] File 'd:/premier 11/PreUI11/PreUI11/PUI11/src/interface/players.ts' is not a module. [2306]

Comment: Stop the server, compile and run it again. Seems like it is not able to find the newly created file.

Answer (score 0):

Try safe parameter `?`:

```
<img src={{playerValue?.playerPhoto}}></button>
```

And

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="playerValue?.playerType">
```